# What type of game is Scorched Earth?

Tags: terminology, worms, scorched-earth

There is a certain type of game where you control a single "tank" character, and fire upon other players, attempting to get the correct firing trajectory and a wide variety of weapons to defeat your opponents.

[image]

Other games like this include the direct take off of Scorched Earth - Gunbound.  Another game that has team of said tanks is the Worms franchise.

[image]

What is this type of game called? I've seen it referred to as a 'Strategy' game, but it doesn't really properly describe it, and isn't like other types of strategy games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia's entry for [*Scorched Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorched_Earth_%28video_game%29) calls it an "artillery video game":

> ***Scorched Earth*** is a popular shareware artillery video game, which is a subgenre of strategy game.

Following the trail, the entry for the [artillery game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artillery_game) genre is informative:

> **Artillery games** are early two or three-player (usually turn-based) video games involving tanks fighting each other in combat or similar. Artillery games are among the earliest computer games developed; the theme of such games is an extension of the original uses of computer themselves, which were once used to calculate the trajectories of rockets and other related military-based calculations. Artillery games have been described as a type of "shooting game", though they are more often classified as a type of strategy video game.

*Worms* can best be thought of as a modern example of the artillery game genre (which is in fact [how Wikipedia classifies the game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worms_%281995_video_game%29)).

Genre is always debatable, of course, but "artillery game" is specific and broad enough to be useful, and the shoe fits.

Comment: I saw the Scorched Earth article, but also saw "citation needed" so I didn't put much stock in it.  The Artillery Game article is much more convincing though. Thank you.  :)